# How to disable scrollbars in Webmethods 8?

Tags: css, scrollbar, portlet, scrollbars, webmethods

I have some portlets made in Webmethods 7 and when I update to Webmethods 8 I have horizontal scroll bars at the bottom of each portlet. How can I disable them?? Is it with CSS?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: I just found out it was set to `overflow:auto`, i'll try hidden thanks