# How to change font size in Webmethods 7.1 (Developer)

Tags: customization, font-size, webmethods

I just started using Webmethods 7.1 (yes, it's oooold but it's a requirement).

As you probably know, it offers no possibility to modify font size/styles through the UI and the sizes are microscopic.

I found and (unsuccessfully) modified some of the .cnf, .xml, .xsd and .xsl files (quite blindly, I must admit, as I don't know much about how they relate to one another). I even added my own styles.css file (again, not sure I did it correctly).

I found this old question [How to disable scrollbars in Webmethods 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100022/how-to-disable-scrollbars-in-webmethods-8?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C153.1263), which goes in the line of what I'm looking for (modifying the styles of the UI) but doesn't specify where the parameters have to be changed.

I'd be extremely thankful if you could help me keep the same prescription in my glasses for a few years longer :)